# Application.Run fails to run with variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I build a C# Windows Form Application. I have problem with the main module. (named by default of "Program.cs")

When I try compile&run:

```
MessageForm f = new MessageForm("Main");
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(f);
```

It fails, (Windows application crash message), but when:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new MessageForm("Main"));
```

It runs great.

- Pay attention to the last command (Application.run(..)); it causes this issue.

Why won't it run with a variable while it runs with "no variable"? (Sorry, I don't pretty much know how to call it).

Why is that way? What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "crashes" - what is the error?

Comment: Try putting the variable declaration below `SetCompatibleTextRendering`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call [Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault.aspx) before creating any windows. It will throw `InvalidOperationException` if called after a window is created. This is why your application is crashing.

Simply move your form variable after the call if you want to write your code this way.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
MessageForm f = new MessageForm("Main");
Application.Run(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're enabling visual styles and compatible text rendering after the first form is created. Try to change the order of the calls like this:

```
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MessageForm f = new MessageForm("Main");
    Application.Run(f);
```

In other words: create the form after calling methods that affect the global behavior of the application...